# How to create a solution file (.sln) from a Web Site in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'll be using the Visual Studio jargon here...

I have a Web Site that lives at `/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/My Project/Code/WebSite`.

I'd like to create a solution file (.sln) file for this Web Site that lives at `/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/My Project/`.

Is there an easy way to create a solution file from a Web Site, and specify the directory for it to be at? Or are there other steps that I need to take...

Comment: [check this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/10/29/converting-a-web-site-project-to-a-web-application-project.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Note: the following applies to Web Site Projects, not Web Application Projects.  WSPs are a bit unique among Visual Studio projects in that they don't have a project file, and all the project settings are stored in the solution file.

There's probably 2 ways to do this:

1. Create a new empty solution in the folder you want.  Then just do Add Existing Website, point it at your web site folder, and you're set!  You may need to customize some settings for your web site to match what you had before.
2. If you already have an existing solution file (which you probably do somewhere on disk), you can move it to the path you want, then update the relative file paths to the web site.  The contents of the solution file will look something like this for a web site project:

   ```
   Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "WebSite1", "..\..\WebSites\WebSite1\", "{AB75CF01-6B54-4BB1-A14A-01A26727FEF2}"
       ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
           TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0"
           Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/WebSite1"
           Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "..\..\WebSites\WebSite1\"
           Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\WebSite1\"
           ... snip ...
           Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/WebSite1"
           Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "..\..\WebSites\WebSite1\"
           Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\WebSite1\"
           ... snip ...
           VWDPort = "47656"
           DefaultWebSiteLanguage = "Visual C#"
       EndProjectSection
   EndProject
   ```

   You can see the relative paths to the folder where the web site actually resides.