# Can't find .SLN file on GoDaddy server

Tags: asp.net, .net

Long story short... I've been asked to do development on an existing .NET website for a small business owner.

I was given a .SLN file (which I can't get to work locally) and was told by the original developer that in order to make changes or additions, I need to make them locally, rebuild the .SLN file, and then deploy it to the GoDaddy server.

I've never used GoDaddy, but I logged into the server and I can't find a .SLN file anywhere on the C: drive.  I see the aspx pages and can make changes to the markup, but the .cs files aren't visible, so I obviously need the ability to update the .SLN file to do anything of worth.

However, I started digging around and found a VisualSVN Server that I can see the files through.  I've never used VisualSVN though.

My thought is if I can somehow get the existing .SLN file from the server then I can load IT locally and work from there.

I know this is kind of a bird's eye view of what's going on, but does anybody have any experience with a .NET site hosted on GoDaddy and have any thoughts or suggestions on what I can do to locate this "missing" .SLN file or re-create it?

Comment: This could go anywhere.  You'll save time and money by asking the original developer and screen sharing, even at $10/min, which I'd assume s/he'd take.

Comment: @DaxFohl Not always an option though.

Comment: This isn't a GoDaddy specific problem either IMHO so I'd be tempted to drop the tag.

Comment: You don't even need a VisualSVN client, as you can just access the VisualSVN server via HTTP with your web browser and navigate through the repo until you find the .sln file, then download it. Of course, you're probably better off using a SVN client to checkout the source, make your modifications, then commit your changes back to the server. I second the notion that you should drop the GoDaddy tag, as that's not important at all to the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, here's all the original developer told me:

"The last time I made changes, both my friend and I were both working off the same SLN, merging changes to each other's code.  Then we would rebuild the solution and drop that solution on the server.  Restarting the server (manually) loads the new solution."

He said that's about all he knew to tell me.

I removed the Godaddy tag.  I included it since I didn't know if some of how it's wired might be specific to Godaddy hosting.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't see the solution, project or source files on the deployment server, you'd only ever see the final built files.

If you have them in SVN you can check out locally, open the project in Visual Studio and build the project there. If it doesn't open you'll need to look into why, usually expectations like some local IIS binding etc.

Comment: It's in SVN (which I've never used) on the GoDaddy server.  Can I transfer the files to my laptop via Remote Desktop?

Answer (score 0):

.SLN file is a Visual Studio solution file that contains information about all files included in the project. This project would then compile into the .DLL file that you will have to deploy to the server. You will not have the .SLN file on the server as it's only relevant in the development environment.

What I think he meant is that you will have to make changes to the site locally, build it and then deploy the output of the build to the server.

Answer (score 0):

VisualSVN is a code repository. If it was populated correctly, it should contain the *.sln (solution) file, along with all the other files and libraries needed to compile your solution (one or more projects). From VisualSVN, you should pull everything you need to your local development environment, make the changes, and re-commit the changes to VisualSVN. If the .sln file is not in the VisualSVN root directory, you may need to either go back to the person who created the repository and ask him/her to load it there, or try something like what is described here: [How to create a solution file (.sln) from a Web Site in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918175/how-to-create-a-solution-file-sln-from-a-web-site-in-visual-studio-2010). I can't attest to whether this process will work. Just add it for you to consider.

Comment: So what I'm doing now is use Remote Desktop Connection to get into the GoDaddy server.  VisualSVN is on there, and I can see the .SLN file through its GUI, but I don't see it in the C:\Repository folder that it's pointing to.  Should I install VisualSVN locally on my laptop and then try to pull everything in there from the remote server?